# How to reset built-in styles for autocompleted and autofilled inputs in 2020? Recipes for Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

**Recipes for Chrome in 2020:**

1) Prevent small font size (browser: 11px, dummy font-family)

2) Reset awesome colors of background (blue, yellow, etc) from Chrome

3) Overturn crash of the "floating label input" pattern on autofill then page is just loaded (the label is initially displayed like a placeholder, and when user start typing it transitions to a small label at the top of the field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Prevent small font size (browser: 11px, dummy font-family):**

[image]

```
input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
  font: 400 15px/18px 'SourceSansPro', sans-serif;
}
```

**2. Reset awesome colors of background (blue, yellow, etc) from Chrome:**
[image]

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
   transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

**3) Overturn crash of the "floating label input" pattern on autofill then page is just loaded (value is empty, no events of change for catch this)**

[image]

Unfortunately, we can listen for the start of an animation, and we can start an animation in response to autofilling using the -webkit-autofill pseudo-class:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
   animation: onAutoFillStart 20s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes onAutoFillStart {
  from  {color: #000}
  to {color: #090909}
}
```

Check Chrome auto-fill for inputs:

```
function inputAutoFillCheck() {
  function onAnimationStart({ target, animationName }) {
    if (animationName !== "onAutoFillStart") return;
    target.parentElement.classList.add("has-txt");
  }
  document.querySelectorAll(".form__input-field").forEach(field => {
    field.addEventListener("animationstart", onAnimationStart, false);
  });
}
inputAutoFillCheck();
```

[image]

**PS**

**It does not works well for autofill then page is just loaded:**

autocomplete="new-password"

Instead of autocomplete="off" use autocomplete="false" ;)

form autocomplete="off" and input autocomplete="off"

$('[autocomplete=off]').val('');

input:-internal-autofill-previewed { font-size: 22px !important }

input:-webkit-autofill {font-size: 22px !important }